# How to fix modules not being recognised after import - PyRTF

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python. I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/grangier/pyrtf/blob/master/examples/examples2.py) example of PyRTF. I can import PyRTF (I've installed `PyRTF3`) but I can't call any of the modules within PyRTF, i.e. `Document()`, `Renderer()`. I've found the module files and PyRTF in my Python folder so I know they exist.

I get the error message from line 48 in `examples2.py`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    DR = Renderer()

    doc1 = MakeExample1()

    DR.Write( doc1, OpenFile( 'Image1' ) )

    print("Finished")
```

> NameError: name 'Renderer' is not defined

EDIT: I found out that the module's only compatible with python 2.7 but they pushed it to 3.x anyway.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Is the code you have posted causing this error message or some code from the examples2.py? Please post the exact code which is causing the error message.

Comment: Do you import the Renderer class? i.e. is there a line like this at the beggining of your file `from PyRTF import *`?

Comment: Yes, I have that line at the beginning

Comment: Andrew, since you found the solution, would you please post it as an answer?  That will help others who find your question.  Similarly, you don't have to delete your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/56222346/2877364) --- if you figured out the problem, why not just post it as an answer?  If nothing else, someone might upvote your answer and you would get some reputation points :) .

Comment: I didn't find a solution to this unfortunately, I went a different direction and I am writing a csv through python and passing it through DocVariables in word-vba.

Comment: Can you explicitly import Renderer; 
from PyRTF.Elements import Document, Renderer